# Deploy/ Copy Feature Class under users AD account with gis Schema,

Tags: arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-pro, sql-server

This question is regarding to SQL Server 2017 and ArcMap or ArcMap Pro environment.

Little history: Currently GIS team deploying/Copying Feature class (FC) from ArcMap 10.4 or Pro under one SQL account and when they copy the FC under that account it by default creates Feature class with GIS Schema (e.g., gis.city, gis.metro etc) and in back end tables created with gis schema as well.

New Approach:
I am planning to use their AD account to deploy the feature class so that way one account password not to be shared and for more security and audit purpose as well.

When I am trying to Copy FC (from Old Srver\geodatabase to New Server\New Geodatabase) under AD account following things happens.

Even though my AD account has default Schema assigned gis not dbo, Still FC gets deployed under dbo Schema (e.g dbo.city) from ArcMap. And my account has db_owner permission.

---

When my AD account has Read/Write Permission and Db_Owner Removed I get below error. copying FC from old server to new server with different database name as well.
" Paste Failed. Failed to Paste **gdb**.gis.city database user name and current user schema do not match. [**gdb1**,"contoso\xxxx".city] DBMS table not found."

I am looking to for...

- How multiple users can deploy/copy/import/ Edit FC under their AD account with keeping gis schema so by default it goes under gis.tablename in SQL always.
- what database level permissions requires for AD users in sQL since I have been trying with various permissions and no success yet.
- Is this a good practice then keeping one SQL account for 10-15 GIS users to perform their deploy/copy/import/Edit tasks?

Comment: Admin accounts are always promoted to dbo; I've never heard of a workaround. Best practice is to use an "ownership" account to own the tables, then grant access to users by roles.  Connecting with AD accounts is dangerous to DBMS integrity and should be avoided.

Comment: Thank you Vince. I tried with read/write privileges and removed sysadmin and db_owner and that's where i received this error Paste Failed. Failed to Paste gdb.gis.city database user name and current user schema do not match. [gdb1,"contoso\xxxx".city] DBMS table not found.

Comment: Also concern is if AD account can copy/deploy or all Admin work from ArcMap so like to avoid using SQL login then i will have to share the password across lot of people which is not safe either.